# Select only when the field has more than one word

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT name FROM clients;
```

Table clients

```
id | name | 
1    John  
2    John Bravo
3    John Alves
4    Jo
```

In postgres, how can I select only names with more than one word? For example. This should be the output:

```
John Bravo
John ALves
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think just test if the name contains a space: `where name like '% %'`
But this will give you some problem if you name can contain space char befor or after the name, like: ' JOHN' or 'Luck '

Answer (score 1):

If **word** means to you a space delimited token, then the following would do the trick:

```
SELECT name FROM clients WHERE name LIKE '% %';
```

But this will also give you those that have empty names made out of spaces only. Also performance-wise, this will be a costly query.

Answer (score 0):

First you may have to find the number of words in the column, then only select where the number of words is greater than 1.

For example:

```
SELECT LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name , ' ', ''))+1 FROM clients;
```

This will return the number of words in each row, which we have in the field `name`.

Then you can proceed putting this in a nested select SQL statement something like :

```
SELECT LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))+1 as mycheck, name FROM clients where (SELECT LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))+1)>1
```

This will return only where words are greater than 1 (>1). Else you can user >2 to return columns with more than 2 words.

Answer (score 0):

**LIKE** is an option, or you can use **split_part**:

```
SELECT name FROM clients WHERE split_part(trim(name), ' ', 2) <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) >= 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**